# MongoDB - Cannot create json schema with INTEGER

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema

I am trying to create a collection with a json schema for validation. I got stuck on the following error and couldn't find anything related to it. I managed to create the schema using *number* type, but *integer* seems to throw this error.

**Using mongodb-driver-sync and mongodb-driver-legacy v4.2.3**

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9 (FailedToParse): '$jsonSchema type 'integer' is not currently supported.' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "$jsonSchema type 'integer' is not currently supported.", "code": 9, "codeName": "FailedToParse"}
```

Tried changing the json schema from Compass and I'm getting the same error, so the problem is definitely coming from the database, not the driver.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's JSONSchema doesn't, [per the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#omissions), support `Integer`.

> **Omissions**
>
> The following are not supported in MongoDB's implementation of JSON Schema:
>
> - The integer type. You must use the BSON type `int` or `long` with the `bsonType` keyword.

```
createTime: {
    bsonType: "int"
}
```

Comment: Ah.. thanks. Do you know any object mapper that uses javax annotations to create such a schema?

Comment: I don't, sorry!